# top of paddle collision detection pong

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is for pong.

I can get collision of the ball and front paddle to fire but not the ball and top of paddle, but this code seems correct for it. This code is inside the ball object. The ball is a square image with correct width and height attributes.

```
    // Paddle collision detection
    // Hits front of paddle
    if ((this.x) == (playerPaddle.x + playerPaddle.width) && (this.y > playerPaddle.y) && this.y < (playerPaddle.y + playerPaddle.height)) {
        console.log("front connect");
        this.vx = -this.vx;
    }
    // Hits top of paddle
    if ((this.x + this.width) >= playerPaddle.x && this.x <= (playerPaddle.x + playerPaddle.width) && (this.y + this.height) == playerPaddle.y) {
        console.log("top connect");
        this.vy = -this.vy;
    }
```

It fires if i change `&& (this.y + this.height) == playerPaddle.y)` to `&& (this.y + this.height) > playerPaddle.y)` but obviously this is wrong, causing it to fire whenever the ball is way below the paddle. It seems like a bug in the browser as it looks correct to me. I'm using chrome which seems to always work well.

Comment: Could you give us a pic or something? This is hard to visualize. But one comment in general is that using == in these types of things is tough if you're running a frame system since in one frame, a ball could move more than one pixel and then you'll miss that moment where the two things are aligned. It should always be greater then/less then.

Comment: why do you use so much brackets? `+` has higher priority

Comment: @matty-d No ==, now top collisions work fine, but front collisions fire both top and front collisions

`if (this.x < playerPaddle.x + playerPaddle.width && this.x > playerPaddle.x && this.y > playerPaddle.y && this.y < playerPaddle.y + playerPaddle.height) {
   console.log("front connect");
   this.vx = -this.vx;
  }
  // Hits top of paddle
  if (this.x + this.width > playerPaddle.x && this.x <= playerPaddle.x + playerPaddle.width && this.y + this.height > playerPaddle.y && this.y + this.height < playerPaddle.y + playerPaddle.height) {
   console.log("top connect");
   this.vy = -this.vy;
  }`

Comment: @matty-d If you are unsure what my game looks like, for an image, you could google image search Atari Pong if you don't mind, thanks. The paddle has a top and front, bottom and back surface, as does the ball. They are rectanglular.

Comment: If we could use == i wouldnt have to write such long ugly if statements like the comment of code i posted (which is a lot longer than my original code). I'm thinking it fires front and top collision when it hits the front because it touches the area designated to "top collision" and "front collision" and if i increase the x position of the ball by 1 pixel for the front collision area this will be solved. I just have to build up the will power to revisit this complex code to attempt it.

Answer (score 2):

Since a 2d ball is circular, you'll need to use trig functions to properly determine a connect with the edge.  I suggest you check the general area first with a "quick check" to prevent slowing down your app.

```
// Paddle Collision Detection
// Start by a global check to see if the ball is behind the paddle's face
if (this.x <= playerPaddle.x + playerPaddle.width) {
    // Get the ball's radius
    var rad = this.width/2;

    // Give yourself a 3px 'padding' area into the front of the paddle
    // For the detection fo collisions to prevent collision issues caused
    // By a ball moving > 1px in a given frame.  You may want to adjust this number
    var padding = 3;

    // Detect if ball hits front of paddle
    // y collision should be from 1/2 the ball width above the paddle's edge
    // to 1/2 the ball width below the paddle's edge
    if (this.x + padding >= playerPaddle.x + playerPaddle.width 
            && this.y - rad >= playerPaddle.y
            && this.y + rad <= playerPaddle.y + playerPaddle.height) {
        console.log("front connect");
        this.vx = -this.vx;

    // Next, do a "quick check" to see if the ball is in the correct
    // general area for an edge collision prior to doing expensive trig math
    } else if (this.y - this.height >= playerPaddle.y
            && this.y <= playerPaddle.y
            && this.x - rad >= playerPaddle.x) {

        // Get the position of the center of the ball
        var x = this.x + rad;
        var y = this.y + rad;

        // Get the position of the corner of the paddle
        var px = playerPaddle.x + playerPaddle.width;
        var py = playerPaddle.y;
        if (this.y + this.height > playerPaddle.y) {
            // if the ball is below the top edge, use the bottom corner
            // of the paddle - else use the top corner of the paddle
            py += playerPaddle.height;
        }

        // Do some trig to determine if the ball surface touched the paddle edge
        // Calc the distance (C = sqrt(A^2 + B^2))
        var dist = Math.pow(Math.pow(x - px, 2) + Math.pow(y - py, 2), 0.5);

        // Check if the distance is within the padding zone
        if (dist <= rad && dist >= rad - padding) {
            // Get the angle of contact as Arc-sin of dx/dy
            var angle = Math.asin(x - px / y - py);

            // Adjust the velocity accordingly
            this.vy = (-this.vy * Math.cos(angle)) + (-this.vx * Math.sin(angle));
            this.vx = (-this.vx * Math.cos(angle)) + (-this.vy * Math.sin(angle));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my ball is drawn with an image, that is square in shape, i wanted that as the old Atari Pong has that. I have set the ball width and height attribute to the same pixel size as the image. I can upload an image as someone else requested it. I will just have to figure out how. I just joined up yesterday.

Comment: Well that sucks for me!  I missed the part of your question that mentioned the ball is square! I'm still going to leave this answer here, though, as it may be helpful to someone who's trying this with a circular ball.